# Sending multiple actions with dispatch in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to Redux and redux toolkit. I'm making todo app to learn it.
In there I can add and remove todos. Now I'm trying to edit it. However I don't see how I can send both the payload of the text I'm adding to my textinput (the one that is the "new" todo) AND the key so I know which one I pressed. Maybe I'm missing something simple or is there something I need to learn that I've misunderstood? Hope my code is not to messy to understand, thanks.

**THIS IS MY SLICE:**

```
export const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todo",
  initialState:{todos:[{text:"test1", key:1}, {text:"test2", key:2}, {text:"test3", key:3}]},
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      const todo = {key: Math.random(), text: action.payload,};
      state.todos.push(todo);
    },
    removeTodo: (state, action) => {
        state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.key !== action.payload);
      },
    clearAll: (state) => {
      state.todos = []
    },
    editTodo:(state, action) => {
      //This is where I want to update the text
    }
  },
});
```

**THIS IS THE APP:**

```
export default function Home() {
    const [text, setText] = useState("")
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
    const [modalText, setModalText] = useState()
    const [newText, setNewText] = useState("")

    const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState()

    const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todo.todos);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleOnChangeText = (val) => {
        setText(val)
    }
        
    const handleAddTodo = () => {
        if (text.length > 0){
            dispatch(addTodo(text))
            setText("")
        } else {
            console.log("error")
        }
    }

    const handleRemoveTodo = (item) => {
            dispatch(removeTodo(item.key))
    }

    const handleClearAll = () => {
            dispatch(clearAll())
    }

    const handleOnEditPress = (item) => {
        setModalText(item.text)
        setShowModal(true)
        setCurrentItem(item)
    }

    const handleEditTodoText = (val) => {
        setNewText(val)
    }

    const handleOnSavePress = () => { 
        dispatch(editTodo(newText))
    }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
{ showModal ?    <EditModule
        onClosePress={()=>setShowModal(false)}
        title={modalText}
        placeholder={modalText}
        onChangeText={(val)=>handleEditTodoText(val)}
        onSavePress={()=>handleOnSavePress()}
        /> : null}
        <View style={styles.topSection}>
            <Text>Add text</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder='Write here'
                style={styles.textinput}
                onChangeText={(val)=>handleOnChangeText(val)}
                value={text}
                onBlur={()=>handleAddTodo()}
            />
            <Button
                text={"Add"}
                onPress={()=>handleAddTodo()}
            />
            <Button
                text={"Clear all"}
                onPress={()=>handleClearAll()}
            />
        </View>
      
        <View style={styles.bottomSection}>
        <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={ ({item}) => (
                <ListItem 
                text={item.text}
                onPress={()=>handleRemoveTodo(item)}
                onEditPress={()=>handleOnEditPress(item)}
                />)} 
                />

        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should always identify a item by its key, instead of its value. So the payload should be `{key, text}`. (Applies to `removeTodo` too)

Comment: Thank you! So "key" is something that redux will recognize as an actual key? (so technically I could use (state, action, key)?

Comment: No, the payload of your action should be an object containing both `key` and `text`. For example: `{key: 1, text: "edited todo"}`. You can see an example at the step 3 of: https://dev.to/arunavamodak/make-a-simple-todo-app-using-react-and-reduxtoolkit-2d4i

Comment: Ahh now I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rashomon had the answer. "The payload of your action should be an object containing both key and text. For example: {key: 1, text: "edited todo"}."